# Is there a way to auto size buttons when they are within a BorderPane in JavaFX?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I'm trying to work with layouts in JavaFX, specifically BorderPanes, my end goal is to make this using buttons [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7crO.png). I was able to get it very close but I had to manually do it by physically changing the size. Below is my code for the GUI. I tried messing around with BorderPane and the button methods but wasn't able to find anything that sized the buttons into their sections.

```
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception{
    BorderPane parent = new BorderPane();
    Scene scene = new Scene(parent, 500, 500);

    //top button
    Button button1 = new Button("top");
    parent.setTop(button1); 
    button1.setPrefSize(500,20); 
    BorderPane.setAlignment(button1, Pos.CENTER); 

    //bottom button
    Button button2 = new Button("bottom");
    parent.setBottom(button2);
    button2.setPrefSize(500,20);
    BorderPane.setAlignment(button2,Pos.CENTER);

    //left button
    Button button3 = new Button("left");
    parent.setLeft(button3);
    button3.setPrefSize(50,500);
    BorderPane.setAlignment(button3, Pos.CENTER);

    //right button
    Button button4 = new Button("right");
    parent.setRight(button4);
    button4.setPrefSize(50,500);
    BorderPane.setAlignment(button4,Pos.CENTER);

    //Stage setting
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.setTitle("Hello JavaFX");
    stage.show();
}
```

Comment: For each button: `button.setMaxSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE)`.

Comment: @Slaw thank you, I don’t understand why this was so hard to find online.